# I tried to solve the following non-homogenous differential equation with variable coefficients but I am not able find solution by any, D.Eq. is:-

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

I tried to solve the following non-homogenous differential equation with variable coefficients but I am not able find solution by any methods and software, the Differential Equation is:-
[image]

i.e. `y''[x]-(s^2/x + k)y[x]=-1`,
where s and k are constants.
I only find complementary function for the above differential equation and unable to get a simple complete solution for the same.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: `DSolve[y''[x]-(s^2/x + k)y[x] == -1, y[x], x] ` returns a solution in terms of hypergeometric functions in v12.2

Comment: I edited your original question to change text to a code block.  This illustrates that you used Set (=) instead of Equals (==) as in @I.M's helpful comment.

Comment: @J.M. has described how to obtain a complete solution, although it is by no mean simple.  Do you have reason to expect a simple solution?  Specifying conditions on the constants might help, but probably not much.